# React render private route after redux(user authentication) is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

PrivateRoute is rendering before Redux gets current user data from the server. What is the best way to fix this issue?

The component looks like below. `userAuth.isAuthenticated` eventually updates to `true` but it renders `<Redirect to="/login" />` first before it gets updated.

```
const userAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    // PROBLEM: this renders before Redux gets user authentication data from the server
    userAuth.isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
  )}/>
)

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Get current user data when user refresh the browser
    // This sets isLoginSuccess: true is current user is logged-in in Redux store
    this.props.getCurrentUserSession();
  }

  render() {
    // Show loading icon while fetching current user data
    if(this.props.user.isFetchingCurrentUserSession){
      return (<div><img src={squareLogo} className="logo-loading" alt="Loading icon" /></div>);
    }

    // Set current user authentication status
    userAuth.isAuthenticated = this.props.user.isLoginSuccess

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/private" component={Private} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    getCurrentUserSession
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: @devserkanYes, part of the code.

Comment: Why don't you directly pass isLoginSuccess to PrivateRoute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

1.Intialize isAuthenticated to null

2.in render return use conditional rendering of the private component

```
const userAuth = {
 isAuthenticated: null
}
```

`in App render return:`

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
      {(userAuth.isAuthenticated!==null)?<PrivateRoute path="/private" 
      component={Private} />:null}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Just implemented this too. Using `null`, `false` and `true` for `isAuthenticated` works well, also with Redux. However, when using a catch-all redirect at the bottom of your `Switch`, it may be more useful to use the same logic for mounting the entire `Switch` rather than the `PrivateRoute`. The same logic can be used for the menu too.